# How can I write a Perl script to extract the source code of each subroutine in a Perl package?

Tags: perl, parsing, package, extract, subroutine

Given a Perl package Foo.pm, e.g.

```
package Foo;

use strict;

sub bar {
    # some code here 
}

sub baz {
    # more code here 
}

1;
```

How can I write a script to extract the textual source code for each sub, resulting in a hash:

```
$VAR1 = {
    'bar' => 'sub bar {
        # some code here 
    }',
    'baz' => 'sub baz {
        # more code here 
    }'
};
```

I'd like to have the text exactly as it appears in the package, whitespace and all.

Thanks.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520235/how-to-tokenize-perl-source-code

Answer (score 17, accepted):

PPI is kind of a pain to work with at the very first; the documentation is not good at telling you which class documents which methods shown in the examples.  But it works pretty well:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use PPI;

my %sub; 
my $Document = PPI::Document->new($ARGV[0]) or die "oops";
for my $sub ( @{ $Document->find('PPI::Statement::Sub') || [] } ) {
    unless ( $sub->forward ) {
        $sub{ $sub->name } = $sub->content;
    }
}

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \%sub;
```

Answer (score 5):

First you need to find out, what package the subroutine resulted from. The book [Perl Hacks](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596526740/) in Hack #58 'Find a Subroutine's Source' recommends module `Sub::Identify`.

```
use Sub::Identify ':all';
print stash_name ( \&YOURSUBROUTINE );
```

This will print the package, the sub is coming from.

Hack #55 'Show Source Code on Errors' shows how to retrieve the source code based on line numbers (from error and warning messages). The code examples can be found here: [example code](http://examples.oreilly.com/9780596526740/perl_hacks_examples.tar.gz)

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the PPI module.

Comment: This looks promising, i'll give it a try