# Perl Module and Sub inventory or Code mapper

Tags: perl

I am not sure what to call this but, is there a module or program out there that will scrape my perl code for use and function calls and build a map.

Example:

```
#package myProgram1

use myProgam2;

print retOne();

print myProgam2::retTwo();

sub retOne{
 return(1);
}
```

I would like to have something that says:

```
myProgram1
 -> Modules
   -> myProgram2
      -> Subs 
        -> printTwo 
 ->Subs
  -> printOne
```

Hope this makes sense.
-Thanks

Comment: [PPI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?PPI)?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575224/how-can-i-write-a-perl-script-to-extract-the-source-code-of-each-subroutine-in-a

Answer (score 1):

See `PPI` and `B::Xref`

```
$ cat junk
use CGI;
print CGI::header();
print retOne();
sub retOne { 1 }


$ perl -MO=Xref junk |grep -A99 "Subroutine (main)"
junk syntax OK
  Subroutine (main)
    Package CGI
      &header           &2
    Package main
      &retOne           &3
```