# Find search for pattern only in particular subroutine

Tags: linux, perl

I want to search for a pattern in .pm  file in particular subroutine alone.
For example, I am searching for $pattern. This $pattern is found in number of subroutine in the pm file, but i want check only in one specific subroutine whether the $pattern is present or not and if the pattern is present i want perform some operation

```
 if (/subroutine\{(.*)pattern(.*)\}/){
  #some code;
 }
else {
  #some code
 }
```

Will this works?
Can you please help me this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575224/how-can-i-write-a-perl-script-to-extract-the-source-code-of-each-subroutine-in-a

Answer (score 4):

[Devel::Examine::Subs](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Examine::Subs) was designed to do things exactly like this (it uses [PPI](https://metacpan.org/pod/PPI) as its backend). In this case, we're specifying only a single file to look in (it can also iterate over directories or in-memory modules).

We then create a regex with our pattern (`data` is our search term here), and finally, `include` only a single sub which will exclude all others in the file. We're looking in the `name()` sub):

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use Devel::Examine::Subs;

my $des = Devel::Examine::Subs->new(file => 'Sub.pm');

my $search_regex = qr/data/;
my $subs_to_look_in = [qw(name)];

my $subs_that_match = $des->has(
    search => $search_regex,
    include => $subs_to_look_in
);

print "$_\n" for @$subs_that_match;
```

Here's the sub I'm looking in within the `Sub.pm` file:

```
sub name {

    trace() if $ENV{TRACE};

    my $self = shift;
    return $self->{data}{name};
}
```

The return is an array reference, so if it's populated with anything (the name of each sub the search term is found in, in this case we're only looking in one) then there was a match:

Output:

```
name
```

Answer (score -1):

You can include the subroutine name and make the regex more specific to the subroutine in which you want to search. Something like:

```
/subroutinename\{(.*)$pattern(.*)\}/
```

This will search for $pattern in the scope of the subroutine.

Comment: That won't match across newlines, the opening brace may not be right next to the sub name (or even on the same line) etc.

Comment: `if (/subroutinename\{(.*)$pattern(.*)\}/)  { 
#some code
 }`
will this works?

Comment: What is `subroutinename` occurs in a comment?